# Install Magento 2 theme on Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, theme

Is it possible in a sensible amount of time?

I didn't find anyone doing it, but maybe there is some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had developed Magento 1 theme and Magento 2 theme. It is possible, but requires **a lot of rewriting**, because of different working mechanisms.

Like the xml layout file, Magento 1 working mechanism is **overwritten**, but Magento  2 working mechanism is **extending**.

Like the js, Magento 2 used the RequireJS to load and run js files, but Magento 1 doesn't .

So, if you install a Magento 2 theme on Magento 1, you will have huge work to finish. It is **very time-consuming**.

Answer (score 1):

It is two different coding standards. While possible to use the same wireframes from the design, you would need to completely redevelop the theme. It is a total rewrite.